# Laravel utilizar método find

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Necesito buscar con el método find un id de la base de datos mediante el controlador y mostrar el usuario con sus dos columnas en una vista. He creado esto, pero no me funciona:

En web.php:

```
Route::get('/alumno/{id}',function($id){
    return view('alumno',['id'=>$id,'nombre'=>$nombre]);
});
```

En AlumnoController.php:

```
public function buscar($id){
    $alumno=AlumnoController::find($id);
    $id=$alumno->get($id);
    $nombre=$alumno->get($nombre);
    return $id,$nombre;
}
```

En la vista alumno.blade.php:

```
echo "Id: ".$id;
echo "Nombre: ".$nombre;
```

Y en el modelo Alumno.php (que no estoy seguro de qué hay que poner aquí):

```
public function buscar($id){
    $alumno=AlumnoController::find($id);
    return $alumno;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes enviar el resultado de alumno a la vista.

En web.php:

```
Route::get('/alumno/{id}', 'AlumnoController@buscar');
```

En AlumnoController.php:

```
public function buscar($id){
    $alumno=\App\Alumno::find($id);
    return view('alumno',['alumno'=> $alumno]);
    //alternativa
    //return view('alumno', compact('alumno'));
}
```

En la vista alumno.blade.php:

```
echo "Id: ".$alumno->id;
echo "Nombre: ".$alumno->nombre;
```

Comment: Lo siento, losu, pero no me funciona. Me dice (en el web.php) que la clase AlumnoController no se encuentra (normal, ya que la clase se llama Alumno y la tabla alumnos). Lo pruebo poniendo Alumno y me dice que no existe. Lo pruebo poniendo alumnos y me dice que no la encuentra. Creo que el problema puede estar en que llamo al controlador para el find, pero no lo se.

Comment: Sigo igual: "Class 'app\Alumno' not found"

Comment: App con a mayúscula.

Comment: en mi pc la carpeta app que contiene el modelo es con minusculas (app). Si pongo App me dice que en alumno.blade.php no existe la variable $alumno.

Comment: Ya esta! Faltaba poner la flecha en lo que le se le pasa a la vista alumno. Muchas gracias, losu.

Comment: Por defecto la carpeta app tiene namespace App.